# How do I install mcrypt for lampp in ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: php, laravel-4, mcrypt, php-extension, lampp

I am new in php framework. So, I am trying to grasp the pros and cons of Laravel 4.2.11

But when I was going to install composer in the laravel's root folder in the htdocs folder of lampp, it showed warning in the terminal that it requires MCrypt PHP Extension.

By the way, I have another php installed in my PC in /usr/bin/php and its version is 5.5.9 and Lampp's php version is 5.6.12

phpinfo() of Lampp showed that It has mcrypt support and mcrypt_filter support, both are enabled.

What should I do to enable artisan to work for Lampp's php?

Comment: why you installing composer in Laravel folder? composer should be installed as global, while you have to Run composer commands under htdocs folder to install/configure different application/packages

Comment: sorry, I already installed composer as global. what I meant that I was using composer install command in terminal to install the dependency packages because composer is supposed to be used as a mean to install packages, right? @Qazi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure the mcrypt module is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Then:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Comment: I already figured it out but thanks a lot for the response. :)